# Setting root route in Sinatra

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sinatra

I want to be able to set my root route to a particular index action. Below is what I have:

```
get '/' do
  redirect '/pokemons'
end

get '/pokemons' do
  @pokemons = Pokemon.all
  erb :"pokemons/index"
end
```

It feels hacky though. I was wondering if there was a rails equivalency of `root to: 'some_controller#some_action' in Sinatra.

Comment: What's hacky about this? this is totally fine.

Comment: you can define such functionality if you wish, but in sinatra, routes and controllers are generally handled in same place. 

copy the contents inside  `get '/pokemon'` to  '/' route,  or  more better, `get '/', '/pokemons' do; #code inside pokemons route; end`

Comment: feels hacky because it redirects, so the url will be `/pokemon` but copying the action in two paths seems not DRY(sorry for late response!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Sinatra::Multiroute (from sinatra-contrib gem), you could specify both routes on one get:

```
get '/', '/pokemons' do
```

See: http://www.sinatrarb.com/contrib/multi_route.html

Answer (score 1):

Not sure it's better than a redirect, but you could also add a catch-all route to the bottom of your file.

```
get '/*' do
  # default route
end
```